# copying to another apps unprotected storage Android

Tags: java, android, storage, sd-card

I'm trying to wirte files to the internal storage actually to an other apps unprotected storage the code I'm using works it just doesn't work when I want to copy to /android/data/com.some.app can this be done or do I have to make the app use root access

Thanks

```
public class tools extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tools);

    }


    public void installflat(View view)
    {   Toast.makeText(tools.this, "This could take a long time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
        File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()  + "/android" + "/data" + "/com.some.app" +"/");
        if (!direct.exists())
        { 
            if (direct.mkdir())
            { //directory is created;
            }}
        installflat_pt2();
        Toast.makeText(tools.this, "try it now", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

    }
    private void installflat_pt2()
    {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        String[] files = null;
        try
        {
            files = assetManager.list("tools");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }

        for (String filename : files)
        {
            System.out.println("File name => " + filename);
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            try
            {
                in = assetManager.open("tools/" + filename);   // if files resides inside the "Files" directory itself
                out = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/android" + "/data" + "/com.some.app" + filename);
                copyFile(in, out);
                in.close();
                in = null;
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                out = null;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());

            }       
        }
    }

    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which error do you get (post your logcat).

Comment: Without being sure about it, I think it will not wokr. I think every app has file access permission for its unprotected storage. You need to cvhange the file access permissions in app A to allow other users acess this file, before being able to acces from app B.

Comment: The external app data directory (i.e. what the app gets via [Context#getExternalFilesDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29)) *should* be writable for every other app as well (although Android 4.4 did change the permission model, it might no longer work or might no longer work in the future - see description of `getExternalFilesDir`). On a sidenote: use an `AsyncTask` because the UI will simply freeze and the "This could take a long time" text will not appear until after the process is done.

Comment: @henry I don't get a log cat error i get this https://www.dropbox.com/s/wzw2liu1k49lc9s/139396212468rrrr8.png  '@boris' what i'm trying to do is is Have my app Replace pictures of a game(like a texture pack)so i can't really set the permissions on the other app, i know it can be done in a file manager. '@zapl' thank for the tip on using AsyncTask that helps alot. i haven't had time to look at 'getExternalFilesDir'